# close() is not working, everytime a new window gets open

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying run the below mentioned code, its not working , everytime a new window gets open instead of closing the current window and opening a window.

```
public class Next2beforendafter {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void launchBrowser() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Users/xyz/Videos/selenium/geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64/geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void verifygoogleTitle() {
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        Assert.assertEquals("Google", driver.getTitle());
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void verifyyahooTitle() {
        driver.get("https://in.yahoo.com");
        Assert.assertEquals("Yahoo", driver.getTitle());
    }

    @Test(priority = 3)
    public void verifybankofindiaTitle() {
        driver.get("http://www.bankofindia.co.in/english/home.aspx");
        Assert.assertEquals("Bank Of India - Home", driver.getTitle());
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void closeBrowser() {
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Selenium Ver.3.0.1

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `driver.quit()` if you want to close the webdriver. `driver.close()` only closes the current window (tab) but leaves the driver session open